# Testing Firebase callable functions with vitest

Tags: firebase, unit-testing, google-cloud-functions, vitest

Hi wrote this function that takes an url and send back metadata of the page scraped with metascraper

```js
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import metascraper from "metascraper";
import metascraperTitle from "metascraper-title";
import metascraperDescription from "metascraper-description";

export const getMetadata = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  try {
    const url = data.url;
    const res = await fetch(url);
    const html = await res.text();
    const metadata = await metascraper([
      metascraperTitle(),
      metascraperDescription(),
    ])({html, url});
    return {
      title: metadata.title,
      description: metadata.description,
    };
  } catch (error) {
    functions.logger.error(error);
  }
  return false;
});
```

I wrote this test to test this callable function:

```js
import {describe , it, expect} from "vitest"
import { getMetadata } from "./getMetadata";

describe('getMetadata', () => {
  it('should return metadata for a given URL', async () => {
    const data= { 'url': 'https://example.com' };
    const context = { };
   
    const result = await getMetadata(data, context);
    
    expect(result).toEqual({ title: 'Example Domain', description: null });
  });
});
```

Here's the error I get

```
 FAIL  src/getMetadata.test.ts > getMetadata > should return metadata for a given URL
TypeError: res.on is not a function
 ❯ node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/common/providers/https.js:392:17
 ❯ Module.<anonymous> node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/common/providers/https.js:391:16
 ❯ src/getMetadata.test.ts:10:26
      8|     const context = { };
      9|    
     10|     const result = await getMetadata(data, context);
       |                          ^
     11|     
     12|     expect(result).toEqual({ title: 'Example Domain', description: null });
```

Can someone please help I don't understand the error, how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [firebase-functions-test](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions-test) package to test your `onCall` functions. The short explanation is that you will use that package to wrap your original function and then you call the wrapped function instead.

Here's a modified example of your function:

```js
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";

export const getMetadata = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  try {
    const url = data.url;
    const res = await fetch(url);
    const html = await res.text();
    return {
      url,
      html
    };
  } catch (error) {
    functions.logger.error(error);
  }
  return false;
});
```

And here's a test that will pass successfully:

```js
import { describe , it, expect } from "vitest";
import { getMetadata } from "./getMetadata";
import firebaseFunctionsTest from "firebase-functions-test";

// Extracting `wrap` out of the lazy-loaded features
const { wrap } = firebaseFunctionsTest();

describe('getMetadata', () => {
  it('should return metadata for a given URL', async () => {
    // Wrap your function here and then call your wrapped function
    const wrappedFirebaseFunction = wrap(getMetadata);
    const data = { url: 'https://example.com' };
    const result = await wrappedFirebaseFunction(data);

    expect(result.url).toEqual('https://example.com');
  });
});
```

The output:

```
vitest run index.test.js

 RUN  v0.31.0 /Users/foo/temp

 ✓ index.test.js (1)

 Test Files  1 passed (1)
      Tests  1 passed (1)
   Start at  10:36:23
   Duration  703ms (transform 21ms, setup 0ms, collect 223ms, tests 67ms, environment 0ms, prepare 64ms)
```

You can read more about unit testing functions at [Unit testing of Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/unit-testing).